# Realm column names vs Swift variable names

Tags: swift, realm, realm-migration

I'm trying to create a Realm database that has columns that contain special characters and are all numbers such as '2010' or 'Share%'.

I can create the Realm using Realm Browser and even create a Realm object using http://www.realmgenerator.eu/ but when I put the model in Xcode, Xcode complains about the naming conventions.

```
class Contract: Object {
    dynamic var ContractID = 0
    dynamic var 2016 = ""
    dynamic var 2017 = ""
    dynamic var 2018 = ""
    dynamic var 2016% = ""
    dynamic var 2017% = ""
    dynamic var 2018% = ""
```

Is there some work around? I would love to avoid naming my columns Year2016 or 2017Percent or something lengthy given I want to surface this data in my app.

Comment: [Constant and variable names cannot contain whitespace characters, mathematical symbols, arrows, private-use (or invalid) Unicode code points, or line- and box-drawing characters. Nor can they begin with a number, although numbers may be included elsewhere within the name.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) So no, there is no workaround.

Comment: @heinst, please post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to follow the variable naming restrictions of Swift. According to the [Swift Programming Language Manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html), `"Constant and variable names cannot contain whitespace characters, mathematical symbols, arrows, private-use (or invalid) Unicode code points, or line- and box-drawing characters. Nor can they begin with a number, although numbers may be included elsewhere within the name."`. This explains why Xcode did not like the variable names and symbols in them, and there is no workaround for naming your variables as described in your question.